# MethodBase.Invoke Method

Tags: c#, methods, reflection, parameters, invoke

I am trying to understand how reflection works so my question is that when I want to invoke some method in assembly why do I send method parameters as an object array and not as a string?

For example I want to invoke this method it gets string parameter but I send arguments as a object array. As far as I know object cant be converted into a string so how it converts it?

```
public string Display(string Name)
    {
        return Name;
    }
```

Comment: Please read `C# in Depth` or `CLR via C#`, they will give you way more structured understanding of what reflection is and when to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MethodBase.Invoke` allows calling methods with many parameters of arbitrary types.

`MethodBase.Invoke` allows you to call any method with any paramaters, including your `Display(string Name)` but also `MyMethod(int val)` and `object[] params` give callers of `Invoke` the ability to provide parameters of any type.

---

Re:

> as far as I know object cant be converted into a string so how it converts it

What is happening here is boxing, please check out [Boxing and Unboxing (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/boxing-and-unboxing).

If you try to call your method with parameters with incorrect types it will not work.

The code snippet below will produce the following output.

```
MagicClass.ItsMagic() returned: 900, type: System.Int32
Object of type 'System.String' cannot be converted to type 'System.Int32'.
```

```
public class MagicClass
{
    private int magicBaseValue;
    public MagicClass() { magicBaseValue = 9; }
    public int ItsMagic(int preMagic) { return preMagic * magicBaseValue; }
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var m = new MagicClass();

    MethodInfo magicMethod = m.GetType().GetMethod("ItsMagic");
    object magicValue = magicMethod.Invoke(m, new object[] { 100 });

    Console.WriteLine($"MagicClass.ItsMagic() returned: {magicValue}, type: {magicValue.GetType()}");

    try
    {
        object magicValue2 = magicMethod.Invoke(m, new object[] { "One hundred" });
    } catch (ArgumentException ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); }
}
```

MagicClass is borrowed from [MethodBase.Invoke Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.methodbase.invoke?view=netframework-4.8#System_Reflection_MethodBase_Invoke_System_Object_System_Object___) 's doco.